# Autowired Hibernate Template lost session in when used in threads

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

I am working on a spring hibenrate application and stuck at a point.
I have only 1 controller having only one service. service update the data in the database and returns it updated id to the client and start the thread.

```
    final Template template = templateBL.getTemplateById(Long.valueOf(templateId));

    Long templateStatusId = templateBL.updateTemplateStatus(template);
    Thread thread = new Thread(templateBL.setTemplate(template, templateStatusId));
    thread.start();
    return templateStatusId;
```

on thread.start() i get this error

```
Exception in thread "Thread-8" org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:72)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getBatcher(SessionImpl.java:297)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:770)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2082)
at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:62)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:628)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:83)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1853)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:369)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:111)
at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:272)
```

am using hibernate template autowiring and apply @transactional on my DAO layer.my config are :

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <!-- currently set to UPDATE -->
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
 <bean>
 <bean id="transactionManager" 
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
          <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" /> 
 </bean>
```

am not getting what possibly could go wrong. Please help.

Comment: Where is the transaction manager ?

Comment: can you show more code (for example sql queries)

Comment: @ArunPJohny  <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak 
hibernateTemplate.save(templateStatus);

TemplateStatus templateStatus = (TemplateStatus) hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().get(TemplateStatus.class, id);

result = hibernateTemplate.find(FROM_TEMPLATE_STATUS+(String)whereClause);

Comment: I am sure am missing some configuration required by the thread, when am using it without thread application is running successfully without any error

Comment: JB Nizet give you right answer.

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate sessions are not thead-safe, and must not be used by multiple threads. If you start a new thread, this new thread should get a new session from the session factory. If you pass an entity to a new thread, you should first detach the entity from the session.

Otherwise, as your code does, any attempt to initialize a lazy collection will call methods from the session. Either the session will be closed (from the first thread), leading to the Exception you got, or it won't, but then you'll have a shared session between two threads, which will cause all sorts of random problems.

Comment: thanx for replying JB,  but am autowiring hibernate template and i suppose it will manage session by itself.
@Autowired
HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate; 
  <bean id="hibernateTemplate" 
configuration defined in hibernate xml file class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate"> 
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

Comment: Yes, but it seems you're passing an attached entity from one thread to another. The attached entity is linked to the session that was opened in the first thread.

Comment: @HimanshuArora please mark it as answered , so that this doesnt show up in unanswered section